# Всего-то[-]навсего — нужен ли дефис?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пишется ли слово всего-то-навсего именно таким образом? Или все-таки раздельно: всего-то навсего? Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Русский орфографический словарь** фиксирует написание с двумя дефисами:

***всего-то-навсего***.

См. [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Всего-то-навсего&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&all=x)

Answer (score 3):

Правильно (согласно орфографическому словарю под ред. Лопатина и справочнику за 2012 год): ***всего-то-навсего***.

В то же время в Нацорпусе такая запись вообще не встречается, в то время как наречие "всего-то навсего" указано в 47 примерах:

Тайны в нашем мире есть даже у компаний, **всего-то навсего** торгующих психотропной сахарной водой, подцвеченной экстрактом кошенильного червя. [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]

**Комментарий**

Возможно, это новая форма письма, которую еще не все освоили, а может быть, просто не согласились с ней.

Старая форма выглядит привычнее. Можно, например, сравнить с наречием ***точь-в-точь***, но там В ― бывший предлог, **симметричная конструкция**.

Не думаю, что ***всего-то навсего***  так уж противоречило нормам письма, вспомним, например,  наречные выражения с повтором и раздельным написанием: ***чин чином, честь честью, честь по чести***.